# Pry not finding installed gems (ruby 2.2.0, rvm)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

## tl;dr

Pry can't find several of my installed gems because the gems found by `Gem::Specification` are different than the gems found by `gem list --local`. The ruby versions are the same, and the path to the found and not-found gems seems to be the same.

I'm thinking that I must have some mix up with paths or ruby versions, but I can't find the culprit. Any ideas of how to untangle this?

---

## Details

I'm running ruby 2.2.0 using rvm on OS X Yosemite, and I'm having an issue getting pry to find several of my installed gems (in particular, pry-doc).

Here are my versions:

```
lee$ ruby -v 
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]

lee$ pry -v
Pry version 0.10.1 on Ruby 2.2.0

lee$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.0 (2014-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/lee/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--omg"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /opt/sm/bin
     - /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
     - /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
     - /opt/sm/bin
     - /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
     - /opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
```

Listing gems via the command line returns what I expect:

```
lee$ gem list --local | grep 'pry'
pry (0.10.1)
pry-doc (0.8.0)
pry-git (0.2.3)
pry-nav (0.2.4)
pry-rails (0.3.4)
```

And the paths for both pry and bash seem to be the same

```
lee$ gem which pry
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry.rb

lee$ gem which pry-doc
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/pry-doc-0.8.0/lib/pry-doc.rb

pry(main)> $ pry
From: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/core_extensions.rb @ line 41:
...
```

However, in pry, the gems available to be installed are controlled by `Gem::Specification` from the rubygems library. Running the following:

```
# I know this method is a mess, but it does the job
def prys
  Gem::Specification.sort_by{ |g| [g.name.downcase, g.version] }
    .select { |g| g.name =~ /pry/ }
    .group_by{ |g| g.name }
    .map { |name, versions| 
      "#{name} (#{versions.map { |v| v.version.to_s }.join(', ') })" 
    }
end

prys
```

returns:

```
=> ["pry (0.10.1)", "pry-rails (0.3.4)"]
```

---

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling as well as hunting around for another copy of the found gems, but no luck. I can't figure out the pattern for what's being returned either.

Any ideas of what to try next?

Comment: You may want to open a new issue with pry on github.

Comment: I'm experiencing the issue in pry, but it's because of the unexpected output from the rubygems class.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure it out, so I figured that there was some issue with how my gems were being saved. I tried `rvm remove 2.2.0 --gems` and then reinstalling, and that solved the issue.

I'm still not sure what precisely was the problem, so if anyone has next-level troubleshooting steps, that's probably still be useful to share.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with pry-rails and ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.6. I use rvm to remove ruby and install it again, and everything works.

However, come to think of it, I guess that the real problem is `spring` is running somewhere with an old gemset. After you install the gem using bundler, you should type `spring stop`, then run `rails c` again. It should run ok.